# Not getting right output when using pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am getting some errors. Any clues where I am going wrong? I think I am applying the right logic.

```
int* adderFunction(int a, int b)
{
    int result;
    int *pResult;
    pResult = &result;
    result = a + b;
    return (pResult);
}
```

Comment: You are returning the address of a local variable: just return an `int` and `return result;`

Comment: Do not return the address of a variable of local

Comment: @user1437027 C++ is easier than you think `int adderFunction(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`. There is no need for anything more complicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You are trying to return pointer on local variable, which is destructed after return from function.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to local variable `result`. When you return from the function it no longer exists but you are returning a pointer to it,.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a pointer on the **stack**, and trying to return that pointer which gets deleted after you finish executing the code. If you want to create something on the **heap** instead, you need to use the `new` keyword.

However your problem can be solved a lot simpler:

```
int adderFunction(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the pointer that is out of scope after function ending. This is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 0):

pResults points to a stack varible. You should use `new` if you want the the data to be allocated on the heap instead. But the you most remember to deallocate it later. I'd prefer

```
int adderFunction(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

You can also do like this if you want to keep the pointer notation

```
void adderFunction(int a, int b,int* pResult)
{
    *pResult=a+b;
}
```

Comment: Good that this is the only answer with code, bad that you included a second version of the function. There's no merit to writing this function using pointers (or new either).

Comment: No, you are probably right. However, this person seem to be learn c++ and if the day comes up where something like this must be done, this is how it should be done.